# <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.logo"/> is not working in typo3 and coming as it is in the code whle inspecting the code.why?

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.1.x

what can I do so that typo3 website recognize the following code:

```
      <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.logo"/>
```

and display the image included in setup.ts as:

```
    lib.logo = IMAGE
    lib.logo.file = fileadmin/template/img/logo.png
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Text Instead of Image

```
lib.logolink = TEXT
lib.logolink.value(
    <a class="Class Name" href="{$baseURL}"><img src="../images/logo.png" alt="" /></a>  
)
```